# Chrome Extension Controlled Rollout Across Multiple Updates

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

For any Chrome extension developers that have used "Controlled Rollout", I'm curious if using the max deploy percentage field in CWS will persist across multiple updates?

For example, we've used controlled rollout previously to deploy to 25% of our users, and that has worked well. But this has just been for a single extension update, such as going from 1.0 to 1.1. But let's say we want to go from 1.1 to 1.2 and still keep the same 25% users in the upgrade group. We'll ultimately roll to 100% of our users, but this may span a couple of updates before we do. Any idea if this is possible? The documentation below doesn't say anything about it:

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#control-how-fast-your-app-reaches-users

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been sitting here a while, but I had this same question. After contacting chrome web developer support, the answer I received is that it is a random group of users from both previous updates that will get the new version. We have had this experience as well when using controlled rollout through multiple versions

Example :

- 100% of users on version 1.0
- Run controlled rollout to 10% of users to 2.0, 90% remain on version 1.0
- Run controlled rollout to 10% of users to 3.0, a mix of users from both 2.0 and 1.0 will get the updated version (3.0)

As an aside, all new users who download the extension will receive the latest version in the chrome store, regardless of controlled rollout

Comment: What happens in the event that a current release (1.0) is at say 25% and a new release (1.1) is pushed at say 25%.  Does that automatically update everyone on 1.0 to 100% or would it keep users on 1.0 at 25% and users on 1.1 at 25%?